# Looking for a nice and unique word that resemble the general usability of a device

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a nice and unique word that resemble the general usability of a device. Let's assume we have a smoke detector that is installable on any heater, so what should I call it?

> **e.g.** General installable smoke detector on heaters?!!

I am looking for something sounds nice .

Comment: The most common ones I can think of are ***general-purpose***, ***multipurpose***, or ***universal***. In the context of being installable on any type of something, universal is the one I'd go with. See universal remote control, universal adapter etc.

Comment: Nice and unique? Please give us more info.

Comment: If by *resemble* you mean *highlights* or *points to*, you can describe the device as *generic*. Is this what you meant?

Comment: As Lawrence's comment hints, you're not using the word "resemble" in a standard way. I think you might mean "represents."

Comment: I guess the word you're looking for is **compatible**. *This smoke detector is widely compatible and can be installed on any heater*.

Comment: For general usability in terms of ease of use of a product or device (usually electronic) I'd phrase it as **user friendly** or **intuitive**.